# Dock settings missing in gnome-control-center after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dock, gnome-control-center, ubuntu-dock

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and am missing the Ubuntu Dock settings, i.e. in `gnome-control-center` the dock settings are blank:

[image]

I think I might be missing the "`ubuntu-dock`" package, but can't find this anywhere in the software centre.

Also the `gnome-control-center` was completely missing after the update, and I had to install this separately - not sure if this is related.

I think this is different from [ubuntu-dock settings not accessible in gnome-control-center by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default) because changing the type of GNOME session doesn't fix the problem. If I go for GNOME* I get no Dock settings section at all, and if I got for Ubuntu* I get the blank Dock settings section described above.

Output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`:

```
rob@rob-pc:~$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7
  Version table:
     0.7 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`?

Comment: `rob@rob-pc:~$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7
  Version table:
     0.7 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages
`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ubuntu Dock doesn't seem to be installed, you can verify it by running

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

There should be an `Installed: (none)` line in the output. If so, you may install it by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

---

If Ubuntu Dock is installed and you still don't find the settings, see this: [ubuntu-dock settings not accessible in gnome-control-center by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default)

Comment: Checking the `cache` shows it is installed. I tried to `apt install` it anyway and it says nothing was added or updated. However, I still cannot see it. Any other idea?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Have you checked this https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default? In any case dock settings are accessible by other means. If you want any particular customisation, search here or ask a new question.

Comment: After searching Google, this question is exactly what I wanted to do and it had the exact same issue, but your solution did not fix it; **however, following the link provided and using the `cog wheel` fix helped**

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Then it's not "*the exact same issue*", is it? In your case you have `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` package installed, but here OP doesn't have the package installed (clear from the provided output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`).  Even the symptoms are not identical too, are they? Here the "Dock" section is present in *Settings*, but completely blank, whereas in your case if I'm not mistaken "Dock" section is not present at all.

Comment: just a reminder, in my case I had to reboot

Answer (score 10):

This issue might be caused by issues during the upgrade. Try reinstalling Ubuntu dock:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This may or may not repair things that apparently went wrong during the upgrade.

Comment: Dock was indeed not installed and I installed it per other post (`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`).  But then I took @vanadium's suggestion and force-reinstalled ubuntu-desktop.  After reboot, it came up with "What's New in Ubuntu?" -- which did not appear following the botched upgrade earlier this week.  Thanks.

Comment: The reinstall of the ubuntu-desktop metapackage indeed might have drawn in other little things that may have been missed during the upgrade. Upgrading is not always seamless, in particular in more customized installations. Many people usually recommend to install fresh rather than upgrade. I normally do, except last time: my upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 went flawless. Glad it worked.

Comment: This helped me after upgrading from Ubuntu 19 to 20 LTS. Not only for the settings, my complete gnome bar was gone after the upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

## Background

Even though the OP stated the following does not work on his machine, **it DID work on my laptop**...

> "I think this is different from [ubuntu-dock settings not accessible in gnome-control-center by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default) because changing the type of GNOME session doesn't fix the problem. If I go for GNOME* I get no Dock settings section at all, and if I got for Ubuntu* I get the blank Dock settings section described above" ~~ OP

As Pomsky suggested in the comments of his answer, **linked above,** provided an additional, but a different solution that worked for me after his answer didn't work. **So for future reference from those coming from Google...**

> "Ubuntu dock setting is accessible only from the GNOME session(s) customised by Ubuntu, not from the default GNOME session(s).
>
> When you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an Ubuntu (and/or Ubuntu on Xorg) option.
>
> Choose Ubuntu (or Ubuntu on Xorg) instead of GNOME (or GNOME on Xorg)." ~~ Pomsky

## Situation

I had Ubuntu Dock installed but the Dock option was **not** showing up anymore. Had it before, but don't know when it disappeared.

I verified I had it installed with the `apt-cache` command below. I did not have a `Installed: (none)` value but an actual number value.

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

## Fix

1. Restart Linux
2. Change the session type you log-in with via the cogwheel (⚙️).

   - Choose either `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu on Xorg`.
   - **Don't** choose some other option like `GNOME`

[image]

In the picture above, I had 3 items to choose from. So I chose `Ubuntu` and logged in.

If you don't have 3 options, then this solution probably won't work for you. Let me know in the comments otherwise.

Comment: This answer is actually valid for this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default

Comment: @pomsky Yes, the link you just provided is the exact same link I had in the answer for a while now. I had Googled my issue and this question came up. This answer is for future reference as stated in the answer.

Comment: Okay, but I just don't see the point here. 1. not exactly the same issue, 2. not even identical symptoms (*blank* dock settings vs. *missing* dock settings), 3. link to the other question is already mentioned by OP with the reason why this question is different ("*I think this is different from [...] because changing the type of GNOME session doesn't fix the problem...*").

Comment: @pomsky I see, I didn't see the OP indicate that this method didn't work.

Comment: That's actually the answer that worked for me on Disco Dingo (Gnome 3.32.1). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just Install "Dash to Dock" extension from software centre.and then play with settings. This package is AKA [gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu%20dock) and is available in the repositories for 17.10 and 18.04 ATM. Future versiona may also be supported. See the link above.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** How is this answer any better than the other answers?  You have enough reputation to leave a comment...