# Dock settings seems to have vanished

Tags: 17.10, gnome-control-center, ubuntu-dock

I just rebooted and noticed the dock was missing. I was messing with the auto-hide functionality earlier, but decided to leave it on. As previously mentioned, now it's gone, though I can see it again by using the super key to open the launcher. As you can see in the screenshot, everything is there but the Dock option.

[image: settings dialog]

Any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: See if any of the other questions helps: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967590/dock-settings-missing-in-gnome-control-center-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default).

Comment: Thanks pomsky, the second link clued me in. For some reason, I was booting into a cinnamon, though I never actually chose that. Swithcing it back to the Ubuntu gnome session worked.