# No option to mirror Displays on 18.04 - DELL M3800

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

I don't find an option to mirror my Displays on Ubuntu 18.04:

I am running Ubuntu on a Dell M3800 with hybrid graphics.

[image]

What might cause this?

Result of `sudo lshw -c display`

```
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

When booting from Live USB the options also is not avaiable.

Switching to the NVIDIA Driver `340.107` from `nvidia-340` didn't fix it.

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Update**
The output of `xrandr --query`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 connected 1920x1200+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: where is display one - it only shows 2 and 3 , or better said how did you connect your displays?

Comment: Display one is the built in display of the notebook and it is turned of. Turning it on doesn't show the mirror option neither, displays are connected via HDMI and Mini DisplayPort (DELL M3800)

Comment: please give us more info: is it ubuntu or one of the official flavours like xfce or mate etc... - or have you installed several of these? is it still a new installation or a heavily edited and what is your grafic device `sudo lshw -c display` - try running a live session from usb/dvd and check if it is the same on there.

Comment: It is not heavily edited. It is Ubuntu 18.04, no flavour.

Comment: okay it is hybrid grafix - so I have no clue except to point you to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics or http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/ sorry

Comment: Thanks. When booting from Live USB the mirror option is also not available.

Comment: okay so mostlikely a driver issue, so try the ubuntuhandbook link even though 2 yrs old this might get you further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86251/discussion-between-db429-and-alexander-zeitler).

Comment: Switching to the NVIDIA Driver `340.107` from `nvidia-340` didn't fix it.

Comment: By mirroring, do you mean having both displays show the same content, or have them overlap?

Comment: Possibly this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170434/how-to-set-3-displays-as-follows-primary-mirror-of-primary-and-secondary

Comment: I mean displaying the same content

Comment: Try this  command xrandr --query  Ubuntu should tell you what display ports are in use, from the documentation, Ubuntu will only give the Join option if more than two displays are connected. From your pics I see display 2 and 3, so if Ubuntu thinks more than two is being used, that's why you may not be getting the mirror option.

Comment: I added the output of `xrandr --query` to the OP.

Comment: From your output it's as I stated, your system sees three screens, that's why you don't have the option for the mirror.

Comment: try xrandr --output eDP --off, I'm assuming that eDP is your notbook display. Hopefully Ubuntu will only see two displays at this point, and allow to you to mirror at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this answer: [How can I mirror one of the screens in a 3-monitor setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576870/how-can-i-mirror-one-of-the-screens-in-a-3-monitor-setup) try using:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --output HDMI-1-2 --output HDMI-1-2 --same-as HDMI-1-1
```

In the accepted solution above, screen 3 is mirrored to screen 2 but the primary screen is not mirrored.

---

Another option is switching to Unity desktop: [GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04 and multi monitor setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030740/gnome-in-ubuntu-18-04-and-multi-monitor-setup)

Click the gear icon next to the `Sign In` button as shown below:

[image: Ubuntu 5 DE.png]

**Note:** Fresh 18.04 installs may need to install Unity Desktop. 16.04 Upgrades will likely have Unity in place by default. See: [How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 desktop use Unity (be like Ubuntu 14.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040890/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-desktop-use-unity-be-like-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thanks, can you also please add how to undo the `xrandr` changes?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler use `xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --pos 0x1920` assuming monitor two sits to the right of monitor 1. The best solution is to run `xrandr` and not the positions before using `--same-as`. Of course you can always reboot too.

Answer (score 2):

The other very quick solution on both 18.04 and 19.04 is to use the keyboard shortcut: [Windows key + p] and then cycle through to get the right configuration.

Comment: Works on 20.04 for me as well.